# I want to hide WMS layer in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, folium

I want to hide WMS layer in Leaflet. But in
a condition, display again.
I tried removelayer. But once
It is removed, it can not add again.

here is the relevant code (generated with folium):

```
if (zoom > 9) {
  map_8e07456499fc4593a61b0bcabd1ab7cf.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    if (layer["options"]["attribution"] == "jeo1") {
      console.log("***   ", layer["options"]["attribution"]);

      var url =
        "http://localhost:8182/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/map/jeo_yas2wms.map&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=jeo_yas2&SRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=" +
        bbox +
        "&WIDTH=1160&HEIGHT=540&FORMAT=image/png";

      map_8e07456499fc4593a61b0bcabd1ab7cf.removeLayer(layer);
    }
  });
}
```

I need normally get the map removed when I have zoom < 9.

What do you suggest?

Comment: You write "once It is removed, it can not add again". How did you try to add it again?

Comment: I'm baffled that `url` is being assigned to, but never used in its scope. I have that feeling that something deeper is being misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by modifying `layers` in `setParams`.